# Find rectangles recursively

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a list of overlapping rectangles. I need find a list of lists in which all the overlapping rectangles are returned. For example, in a list of 7 rectangles, if 4 rectangles are overlapped and rest are separate then a list of lists should look like this:

```
[0]: r1, r2, r3, r4
[1]: r5
[2]: r6
[3]: r7
```

I know I have to perform a hit test. I am looking for an algorithm or an example to create chains please.

Thanks

I have tried this code: Sometimes it works, sometimes, it throws index out of bound kinda exception.

```
while (rects.Count != 0)
            {
                listOfRects.Add(joinRectangles(rects, new List<Rectangle>(), rects[rects.Count - 1]));
            }

        private List<Rectangle> joinRectangles(List<Rectangle> rects, List<Rectangle> tempRects, Rectangle curRect)
        {
            for (int j = rects.Count; j-- > 0; )
            {
                if (hitTest(curRect, rects[j]) == true)
                {
                    if (tempRects.Contains(rects[j]) == false)
                    {
                        tempRects.Add(rects[j]);
                        curRect = rects[j];
                        rects.Remove(rects[j]);

                        j--;

                        joinRectangles(rects, tempRects, curRect);
                    }
                }


            }


            return tempRects;
        }
```

If I supply these coordinates then I should get a list of 4 lists like this:

```
    [0]: 1 rectangle
    [1]: 3 rectangles
    [2]: 1 rectangle
    [3]: 1 rectangle


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<rectangles>
  <rectangle>
    <X1>50.833333344375</X1>
    <Y1>100</Y1>
    <X2>53.833333344375</X2>
    <Y2>127.00000004975</Y2>
  </rectangle>
  <rectangle>
    <X1>136.500000033125</X1>
    <Y1>100</Y1>
    <X2>139.516666655625</X2>
    <Y2>127.00000004975</Y2>
  </rectangle>
  <rectangle>
    <X1>50.833333344375</X1>
    <Y1>130.647222172472</Y1>
    <X2>53.833333344375</X2>
    <Y2>157.647222222222</Y2>
  </rectangle>
  <rectangle>
    <X1>136.500000033125</X1>
    <Y1>130.647222172472</Y1>
    <X2>139.516666655625</X2>
    <Y2>157.647222222222</Y2>
  </rectangle>
  <rectangle>
    <X1>136.500000033125</X1>
    <Y1>100</Y1>
    <X2>139.516666655625</X2>
    <Y2>157.3333333830833</Y2>
  </rectangle>
  <rectangle>
    <X1>179.3333333775</X1>
    <Y1>100</Y1>
    <X2>182.3333333775</X2>
    <Y2>157.3333333830833</Y2>
  </rectangle>
</rectangles>
```

Comment: How efficient do you have to code it? And how many rects do you have (round about)? I have some solutions in my mind but they aren' optimal.

Comment: What happens when `r8 and r9` , `r9 and r10` overlap but `r8 and r10` not?

Comment: It is a chain, it should connect r8, r9, r10

Comment: Are you calculating their overlap by the point they start and width/heights etc. or is it not that complex? Also, are the rectangles on a canvas in WPF or windows forms or just objects?

Comment: Rectangles are objects. The overlapping is being calculated using x1, y1, x2, and y2 coordinates

Comment: @Jhapak : If an answer helps You, You should accept that answer... (Will give credit to the people helping you.) Currently none of your questions have accepted answers, which only should be the case if no answer has helped you...

Answer (score 0):

Written quicly from scratch before you posted your own code.
You have a rectangleList, and want to group them by overlap groups.

You use this groupRectangles function

```
public List<List<Rectangle>> groupRectangles(List<Rectangle> rectangleList) {

List<List<Rectangle>> groupOverlappedRectangles = new List<List<Rectangle>>();

foreach (Rectangle r : rectangleList) {
    bool overLap = false;
    foreach (List<Rectangle> liste : groupOverlappedRectangles) {
        if (overlapsRectangleList(r,liste))
        {
                liste.add(r);
            overLap = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!overLap) {
        List<Rectangle> newOverlapList = new List<Rectangle>();
        newOverlapList.add(r);
        groupOverlappedRectangles.add(newOverlapList);
    }
}
return groupOverlappedRectangles;
}

public bool overlapsRectangleList(Rectangle r, List<Rectangle> listeOver)
{
    foreach (Rectangle rOver : listeOver) {
        if (r.IntersectsWith(rOver)) {
            return true;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the code is not returning the chain.

Comment: @Jhapak : I added the return statement. It returns a List of List of rectangles. Each List of rectangles contains a chain of overlapped rectangles, and you have all of them in the global List.

Comment: The problem is not with the return statement. groupOverlappedRectangles doesn't contain the correct list of chains. Please see my original post to the example. Thanks

Comment: I dont understand: let's say I take a List<Rectangle> containing 7 Rectangles. My method takes it and sends you back a List containing 4 Lists, 1st list: r1,r2,r3,r4, 2nd List: r5, 3rd List: r6, 4th List: r7. I send you back a List of List of Rectangles: List<List<Rectangle>> (double List), but you tell me I missed something ... Could you explain me more why my code doesn't fulfill your wish ? Maybe I can correct it :)

Comment: Please see my original post. I have added the coordinates. When I feed the list, your code is returning list of 5 lists.

Comment: @Jhapak : I've read my code again, there was a mistake in overlapsRectangleList. I added the IntersectsWith method too. Try it again :)

Answer (score 0):

Heres another approach using [`Rectangle.IntersectsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith) and Linq's deferred execution:

```
var intersectingRectangles = new List<List<Rectangle>>();
var alreadyChecked = new HashSet<Rectangle>();
var toCheck = rectangles.Except(alreadyChecked);
while (alreadyChecked.Count != rectangles.Count)
{
    var intersections = toCheck.Where(r => r.IntersectsWith(toCheck.ElementAt(0)))
                               .ToList();
    intersectingRectangles.Add(intersections);
    foreach (var r in intersections)
        alreadyChecked.Add(r);
}
intersectingRectangles.Sort((rl1, rl2) => (-1) * rl1.Count.CompareTo(rl2.Count));
```

Maybe not the most readable way but one of the shortest :)

**Edit**: Here's a demo(difficult with mono without System.Drawing and Rectangles):

http://ideone.com/eOCMN

Comment: Thank you for the reply. There is a problem in the code. intersectingRectangles' count is equal to rectangles count. However, when the chains are creates (see my original post), it should only returned the list of list of chained rectangles.

Comment: @Jhapak: Sorry, didn't have the time to   look closely so i've deleted it. Have a look at the edited version.

Comment: @TimSchmelter. See my comment for question. Your answer does not satisfy `It is a chain, it should connect r8, r9, r10`

Comment: @L.B: Ok, that's true, i don't see how i could modify my answer easily to match that reqirement.  I keep it here anyway if somebody needs something similar. Added a demo.

Answer (score 0):

For each rectangle all earlier groups of rectangles has to be checked. For instance if A and C overlaps, and B and C, but not A and B. If the algorithm receives A, B, C, it will first put A in one list, then B in another list. But when C comes it has to merge both the list with A and the list with B, to the new list containing C. (That's what the other answers seem to have missed.)

```
public static List<List<Rectangle>> SortOverlap(Rectangle[] rectangles)
{
    var result = new List<List<Rectangle>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.Length; i++) 
    {
        var newList = new List<Rectangle>();
        newList.Add(rectangles[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < result.Count; j++) 
        {
            if(result[j].Any(r => r.Overlap(newList[0])))
            {
                newList.AddRange(result[j]);
                result[j] = null;
            }
        }
        result.Add(newList);
        result.RemoveAll(list => list == null);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Edit**:
The overlap check is rather simple to implement, so no need to use System.Drawing or similar only for that check...

```
public class Rectangle {
    ....
    public bool Overlap(Rectangle other)
    {
        return !(this.MinX >= other.MaxX || this.MaxX <= other.MinX ||
                 this.MinY >= other.MaxY || this.MaxY <= other.MinY);
    }
}
```